# Column Space of AA' is equal to column of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my question. How to show that the column space of matrix A
is just equal to the column space of AA'?.. A' represents the transpose of A.
I know that the column space of AA' is a subset of the column space of A
which is just trivial. But the other way around I still used inclusion 
but it seemed that it is going nowhere. Maybe it can be done by some manipulation
or the barbaric way of doing this. I just want to obtain a simple proof. Anyone?

Comment: By the way the size of matrix A here is nxn real matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** If you can show that $A'x=0$ whenever $AA'x=0$, then $\operatorname{nullity}(AA')\le\operatorname{nullity}(A')$ and hence $\operatorname{rank}(AA')\ge\operatorname{rank}(A')=\operatorname{rank}(A)$, i.e. the dimension of the column space of $A$ does not exceed the dimension of the column space of $AA'$.

If you really want a super-duper simple proof, use [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: I think this is a more straight forward proof: Since rank(AA')f  = rank(A) and trivially column space of AA' is a subspace of A. Therefore they have the same rank implies that the dimension of their column space is equal. Then CL(AA')=CL(A).

Comment: @JCAintegral Yes, the proof would be easy if you know that rank(AA')=rank(A), provided that this equality has been proved independently (so that you won't end up with a cyclic proof).

Comment: I guess the answers are using Real matrices